# MapKitでピンを同時に二つ置きたい

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

以下のサイトを参考にさせていただき、MapKitを使って、長押しをした場所にピンを置くプログラムを書きました。

[逆引きswift](https://sites.google.com/a/gclue.jp/swift-docs/ni-yinki100-ios/7-mapkit/pinnianimeshon)

長押しをすると同時に二つのAnnotationを置くようにしたかったのですが、最初の１つのAnnotationしか置くことができません。同時に二つのAnnotationを置くにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    //長押し検知器
    var longtapGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        //長押し検知器の設定
        //長押し時に呼びだすメソッド
        self.longtapGesture.addTarget(self, action: "longPressed:")
        //マップに長押し検知器を追加
        self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(self.longtapGesture)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Location Delegate Methods

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations.last

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
    {
        print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func longPressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

        //指を離したときだけ反応するようにする
        if(sender.state != .Began){
            return
        }

        //senderから長押しした地図上の座標を取得
        let location = sender.locationInView(self.mapView)
        //CLLocationCoordinate2Dに変換
        let mapPoint:CLLocationCoordinate2D = self.mapView.convertPoint(location, toCoordinateFromView: self.mapView)

        //ピンを生成
        let theRoppongiAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        //ピンを置く場所を設定
        theRoppongiAnnotation.coordinate  = mapPoint
        //ピンのタイトルの設定
        theRoppongiAnnotation.title       = "ピン1"
        //ピンのサブタイトルを設定
        theRoppongiAnnotation.subtitle    = "1個目のピン"

        //        //ピンを地図上に追加
        //        self.mapView.addAnnotation(theRoppongiAnnotation)


        var newmapPoint:CLLocationCoordinate2D = self.mapView.convertPoint(location, toCoordinateFromView: self.mapView)
        //ピンを生成
        let secondAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        newmapPoint.longitude += 100
        //ピンを置く場所を設定
        secondAnnotation.coordinate  = newmapPoint
        //ピンのタイトルの設定
        secondAnnotation.title       = "ピン2"
        //ピンのサブタイトルを設定
        secondAnnotation.subtitle    = "2個目のピン"

        //ピンを地図上に追加
        self.mapView.addAnnotations([secondAnnotation,theRoppongiAnnotation])
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

２本目のピンの位置について、緯度にして100度も足してるから２本目が置かれていても画面の外に出てしまっていて見えないのだと思います。

```
var newmapPoint:CLLocationCoordinate2D = self.mapView.convertPoint(location, toCoordinateFromView: self.mapView)

//ピンを生成
let secondAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
newmapPoint.longitude += 100

//ピンを置く場所を設定
secondAnnotation.coordinate  = newmapPoint
```

緯度で１度の距離は100km以上になるので、試すだけなら1度も足せば十分ではないでしょうか。

```
newmapPoint.longitude += 1
```